# UITextField Not really working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm just starting to learn iOS development and Objective C and I'm following Apple's tutorial (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1)

I have a text field that adds a new task to an array. When I press "done" the task is added to the array and it appears in the tableview - but then i get this in the debug:

> [XYZViewController addTaskField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb13348c8c0
>   2014-10-16 18:00:36.120 Tutorial123[7880:1837804] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[XYZViewController addTaskField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb13348c8c0'

Here's the code I have on that file that handles the text field:

```
#import "XYZViewController.h"
#import "ToDoItem.h"

@interface XYZViewController ()

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *addTaskField;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;


@end

@implementation XYZViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if(sender != self.doneButton) return;

if(self.addTaskField.text.length > 0){
    self.todoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    self.todoItem.itemName = self.addTaskField.text;
    self.todoItem.completed = NO;
  }
}


@end
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error? If you don't know, see http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Have you connected connected your IBOutlet called addTaskField to UITextField in your storyboard? What I think is because addTaskField is not connected to any text field inside the storyboard, it is null,and self.addTaskField.text is null, so asking for the length of self.addTaskField.text would throw exception

Comment: I'm sure it's connected because before the error occurs, I see the text I inputted populated in the table, but a second after the error crashes the app. Therefore, it seems like everything is being called and the array is updated, but in the end something happens that crashes everything.

Answer (score 0):

When you were wiring addTaskField button from storyboard did you create an action first then deleted the method in the code and created an outlet?  If that's what happened you have to go back to storyboard click on the button and connection inspector and see that touch up inside doesn't have addTaskField: wired up.  See image below.  I added testAction: action.  You have to press the little x next to View Controller testAction: to delete it.  Let me know if that's what happened.

[image]